Discord bot getting rate limited without exceeding Discords 50 requests per second (3 requests in 53seconds)
I'm making a Discord bot that sends requests for channel renamig every time someone joins or leaves Minecraft server. As the title says, I was far away from breaking the actual rate limit. At one point, I set the delay to be 20 seconds and after the 3rd request, I was still being limited.
@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def update_channel_name():
    global status_check
    try:
        status = server.status()

        channel = bot.get_channel(VOICE_CHANNEL_ID)
        if channel is None:
            print("Voice channel not found!")
            return
        
        if status_check != status.players.online:
            await channel.edit(name=f'Online players: {status.players.online}')
            print(f"Updated voice channel to: {status.players.online}")
            status_check = status.players.online
        else:
            print("-")

    except discord.Forbidden:
        print("Bot lacks permission to edit the voice channel.")
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred : {e}")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    print(f'Bot is ready. Logged in as {bot.user}')
    await bot.get_channel(VOICE_CHANNEL_ID).edit(name=f'Online players: {server.status().players.online}')
    print(f"At start updated channel to {server.status().players.online}")
    update_channel_name.start()

Error
: discord.http We are being rate limited. PATCH *{Channel_ID_link}* responded with 429. Retrying in 580.74 seconds.
Every time i run my code, channel name gets changed about 2 or 3 times and then I get rate limited for 500sec.

Is something wrong with my code? (This is part of my code, the rest is mostly variables)

There's a ratelimit for updating the channel, it's 2 requests per 10 minutes per channel. Since discord has dynamic ratelimits, my guess is that after repeatedly hitting the ratelimit it gave you an even bigger one. Another option might be because of your host since they sometimes share a single IP between a couple of applications (like replit)

Thanks for letting me know that discord has 2 req per 10 minutes for updating channel, didnt know that. I will probably try to create cahnnels instead of renaming them, its 500 req per day so its better.
